# "Till" vs "untill". Which one is better to use and why?

Tags: grammaticality

Why is **"till"** worse than **"untill"**?
I'm not a native English speaker can someone explaine to me why so many native speaker recommnded me to replace **"till"** with **"until"** in the sentence below:

> "...he employed 5% of the population from 2009 till his death".

Is this sentence correct? Or is it incorrect to use **"till"**. Because for me it looks like there's more likely a problem with **"from"** part than with **"till"**. What would be the best way to write this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

“until”, “untill”, “ ‘til” and “till” all mean exactly the same thing.

“untill” is now considered incorrect by many, and the “until” spelling is now 100x as common.

“ ‘til” is an informal shortening of “until”.

“till” is often mistaken for “ ‘til”, even though it is actually the oldest form of the four, so I’d stick to “until” in formal writing.

Comment: how about "from" part? Is it  correct or should I use "since" instead?

Comment: No, we only use _since_ when the action is ongoing. Use _from...until, from...to_ or _between...and_.

Comment: I have tryed to write it in a different way. "He employed more than 5% of the population between 2009 and his death". Would this one be better?

 To be clear. I’m translating an article on economy and I’m trying to say here that he has employed more than 5% of population(of a small town) from a particular date(2009) and this share(>5% of the population he employed) never fell below 5% until his death.

Comment: Between 2009 and 20XX (the date of his death), he provided employment for more than 5% of the population of X

Comment: It might also be worth noting that *"till"* has (commonly used) meanings other than *"until"*, both as a verb (cultivate), and as a noun (cash drawer, glacial tailings).